# useNavigate() function not always working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm building a MERN Web App and I'm going through an issue: when I login with an existing account, after calling an API to the backend and handling the request, it returns the user properties and the JWT Token, I save it and then (using navigate function) I redirect the User to the homepage. It works fine but it doesn't when i relaod the page. I mean in the first load of the page the login works fine and so does the navigate function, but when I reload the page and enter the login data, it does login but does not redirect me to the homepage. I hope it is understandable! This is the snippet of the code which makes the API call and then the redirect:

Login.js

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    try {
            const res = await axios.post(WEB_URL + `/login`, { email, password })
        // console.log(res.data);
        const { token } = res.data.token;
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', token);
        // console.log('logged as', res.data.user.name);
        navigate("/");
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        navigate("/login");
    }
};
```

App.js

```
    const PrivateRoute = () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
        return !!token;
    };

    function App() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Navbar />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={PrivateRoute() ? <Home /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                    <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        );
    }
```

Comment: So what *is* happening when you reload the page? Do you mean the authenticated user is on the home page and reloads and then *something* unexpected occurs? Or are you trying to navigate back to the login page and log in again? Can you clarify the exact reproduction steps.

Comment: @DrewReese what happens is that when i'm in login page, the user gets authenticated but he doesn't gets redirected to the homepage ('/'). this only occurs after reloading the login page e.g. i'm in homepage, i sign out and i login again, it works! ---- i'm in homepage, i sign out, i reload the login page and then login, the user gets logged but not redirected to '/'

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see what is happening then? Is there an error that is navigating to `"/login"` and keeps the user there? Is there something else elsewhere in the code that redirects back to `"/login"`? I don't see any reason at all why `navigate("/")` wouldn't work, so I suspect you've some other code keeping the user on the `"/login"` route. Can you provide a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese just added the App.js code, could it be there?

Comment: It *might* be your home `"/"` route when it checks localStorage. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo (*you can mock the POSY request*) that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese don't really know how to use it, how do i mock the post request? I also think it could be in the Route for '/' , when maybe the PrivateRoute() function gets requested before the token is stored..?

Comment: Sorry, I meant just comment out the `axios.post` line and mock a response value, i.e. whatever you want the `res.data.token` value to be for testing purposes.

Comment: that's the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-wilbur-7rvirj?file=/src/App.js ... I got that the problem is in the PrivateRouter() function, but have no clue on how to fix it, maybe with an async / await on PrivateRoute() ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that when `App` renders it calls `PrivateRoute` ***the function*** and it correctly returns `false` since no user is logged in and the `<Navigate>` component is rendered.

The router is correctly navigated to `"/login"` and the `Login` component is rendered and the user authenticates and is navigated back to `"/"`. Because no state or props or parent component to `App` was updated the `App` component doesn't rerender and doesn't re-check the token in localStorage. This means the `<Navigate>` component is still rendered and the user is bounced back to `"/login"`.

## Solution

Make `PrivateRoute` an ***actual*** React component so the component is rendered/rerendered when the route changes, and so it can recheck the token in localStorage.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
  return !!token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />;
};
```

Render `PrivateRoute` on a layout route that renders the home page.

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit usenavigate-function-not-always-working]